# A question about probability convergence (using the Law Of Large Numbers)

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

I think this problem will help me learn some convergence techniques.

Given $(\xi_j)_{j=1}^{\infty} \sim  \xi$. Supposse that in probability
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \exp ( i s  \xi_j ) \to E[\exp ( i s  \xi )]\quad (n \to \infty)$$

I want to show that

$$ \Pi_{j=1}^n \left[ 1 + \frac{\lambda}{n}  \Big( \exp (i s \xi_j) - 1 \Big)   \right] \to \exp( \lambda ( E[ \exp (i s \xi) ] - 1)) \quad (n \to \infty)$$

My attempt is: denote $X_{j}^n =  \left[ 1 + \frac{\lambda}{n}  \Big( \exp (i s \xi_j) - 1 \Big)   \right]$, $X_n = \Pi_{j=1}^n X_j^n $ and try to show that
$$\log X_n \to \lambda ( E[ \exp (i s \xi) ] - 1)$$

So take the log

$$\hat{X}_n := \log X_n = \sum_{j=1}^n \log X_j^n = \sum_{j=1}^n \log \left[ 1 + \frac{\lambda}{n}  \Big( \exp (i s \xi_j) - 1 \Big)   \right] $$

But I don't know how to conclude.

Help

Comment: Why not use Taylor polynomial? $\log(1 + z) = z + O(z^2)$ any _implicit_ constant universal for $|z| \leq \dfrac{1}{2}.$

Comment: Do you have some reference por this fact?

Comment: You can use Taylor expansion. It is a basic fact from analytic functions theory that such series will converge on the unit disc $|z| < 1.$ Then you will have $\log(1 + z) = z - z^2/2 + \ldots = z + z^2 g(z)$ where $g(z)$ is analytic on $|z| < 1$ (because $g$ is already a power series). _A fortiori,_ $g$ is bounded on every compact subset of $|z| < 1,$ in particular, for every compact subset $\mathrm{K}$ of the unit disc there exists a universal constant (depending solely on $\mathrm{K}$ and $g$) such that $|g(z)| \leq c_{\mathrm{K}}$ for all $z \in \mathrm{K}.$

Comment: In fact, note furthermore that $\log(1 + z) = z + z^2 g(z)$ with $g$ analytic, this formula valid on the unit disc. _A fortiori_, $g$ is also measurable. So, you if you had doubts about "what if the taylor expansion produces something non measurable" the answer is it will not (no Taylor series can ever produce a residue that is non measurable using the same reasoning as just now).

Comment: I'm a little confused. The definition of Big O in probability involves a sequence: somthing like $O(z_n)$, for example. Are you saying say $\log(1+z_n)= z_n + O(z_n^2)$, where  $z_n = \frac{\lambda}{n}  \Big( \exp (i s \xi_j) - 1 \Big)$ ?

Comment: I am not using Big O in probability.

Comment: Sorry, what is the definition of $O(z^2)$?

Comment: There exists a constant such that $O(z^2)\leq c|z|^2.$

Comment: Sorry, I can not conclude the convergence

Comment: If you cannot conclude, then you need to think, alas a little at least!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x-\frac{x^2}{2}\leq\log(1+x)\leq x$, thus $$(X_j^n-1)-\frac{(X_j^n-1)^2}{2}\leq\log(1+(X_j^n-1))\leq (X_j^n-1).$$

For the RHS, by SLLN we have $$\sum_{j=1}^n(X_j^n-1)=\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda(e^{is\xi_j}-1)\to\lambda(\mathbb{E}e^{is\xi}-1).$$

For the LHS we simply note that the quadratic term $$|(X_j^n-1)^2|=\frac{\lambda^2}{n^2}|e^{is\xi_j}-1|^2\leq\frac{\lambda^2}{n^2}\cdot4$$

sums up to $\frac{C}{n}\to 0$ for some $C$. This proves the result with a.s. convergence.

Comment: a.s convergence implies convergence in probability? Why I can not use the proabability convergence directlly ?

Comment: @PSE: yes, a.s. convergence does imply convergence in probability, which is to say it is stronger version of convergence. And a.s. convergence enables us to treat r.v.s as sequences of numbers, since we can fix a sample $\omega$ and study the convergence of $X_n(\omega)$. If we are dealing with convergence in probability, an issue is that you need to show, additionally, that $Y_n\leq X_n\leq Z_n$ with $Y_n,Z_n\overset{p}{\to}X$ implies $X_n\overset{p}{\to}X$. Well, it is not hard to show, but why bother?

Comment: @PSE note this is exactly the same approach as the one commented by me earlier. The difference $\log(1 + z) - z$ is $\leq C|z|^2$ and once you substitute, you get $\frac{C}{n} \to 0$ as commented in the main thread.